# Sort a map by value in javascript and keep one field index to top

Tags: javascript, typescript

May be this is a very simple question on this forum but I couldn't find the answer being novice to javascript.
I have this following code in javascript -

```
Let map = new Map<String,String>
map.set('0', select)
map.set('1', "foo");
map.set('2', "bar");
map.set('3', "baz");
```

I want to sort this map based on value. But index 0 should be on top and others should be sorted. So the final output should be printed as below -

```
[{'0':'Select'},{'2':'bar'}, {'3':'baz'}, {'1': 'foo'}];
```

Could you please help me on this?

Comment: You could sort the keys and access them in order (i.e. `Object.keys(obj).sort()`)

Comment: Applying the accepted answer to your question's code: `map = new Map([...map].sort(([k1, v1], [k2, v2]) => v1.localeCompare(v2)));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the [`Map#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) of the map and sort the array.

To move a certain value to top (or keep this value at top), you need a return value for [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) which reflects the wanted order. In this case a is taken fom the conditions and if [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), like zero, the second part after the [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR) is taken.

```js
let map = new Map();

map.set('0', "Select");
map.set('1', "foo");
map.set('2', "bar");
map.set('3', "baz");

result = Array.from(map).sort(([, a], [, b]) =>
    (b === 'Select') - (a === 'Select') || a.localeCompare(b)
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks Nina .. I have accepted this answer. I have an entry in map as below - 
map.set('0',"Select")
Is it possible to sort other entries and keep the select on top ?

Comment: you need a check for the top value and take the delta of the check. please see edit.

Comment: I am getting below error on (b === 'Select') - (a === 'Select')
The left hand side of an arithmetic operation must be type 'any', 'number','bigint' or enum type

Comment: you could cast the values to number: `Number(b === 'Select') - Number(a === 'Select')`

Comment: Thank you so much :) Wish I could vote you more